# Are Phottix Atlas I and Phottix Atlas II compatible?

Tags: wireless-triggers

I share photography equipment with a friend and he has a set of phottix Atlas I flash triggers and recently the phottix Atlas II was released and its cheaper than Atlas I and it tempting me to get a set, but I am just wandering whether it will be compatible with each other, judging that they are both from the same company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not compatible. See the website: http://www.phottix.com/en/studio-accessories/phottix-atlas-ii-2-4ghz-wireless-trigger.html for details, it's stated very early in the product description. In fact, it says it 4 times in the page, so I'm guessing they get this question a lot...

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not see that. thanks

Comment: @jonleech - No worries, welcome to the site! :)

Comment: That said, the 2.4GHz triggers tend to be a lot more reliable with speedlights than the older 900MHz triggers, especially with Canon flashes (which are electrically very noisy in that part of the spectrum). There is a pretty good market for RFI flash body shields in the strobist world. My hat is off to PocketWizard, who've done a whole lot of work to maintain backward compatibility with built-in receivers in studio strobes and the Sekonic meter modules; there's a lot of trickery in the electronics of the PlusIII to get around speedlight interference.